# how to place heat-map tick label at top of the y-axis instead of middle

Tags: highcharts

I have created heat-mp using High-charts.But tick marks which are generated are placed in the middle of the row instead of top of the row on Y-axis, please have a look at the below image

[image]

Y-axis configuration

```
 xAxis: {
                tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
                 "tickWidth":1,
                 "tickPositions":[0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24],
                 categories: ['12 am', '1 am', '2 am', '3 am', '4 am', '5 am', '6 am', '7 am', '8 am', '9 am', '10 am', '11 am', 'Noon', '1 pm', '2 pm', '3 pm', '4 pm', '5 pm', '6 pm', '7 pm', '8 pm', '9 pm', '10 pm', '11 pm'],
                 "min":0,"startOnTick":false,"maxPadding":0,"endOnTick":false,"minPadding":0,


            },
```

Please let me know how can I fix this.

Comment: A fiddle, or your full chart code, will help. I would have thought that the `tickmarkPlacement: 'on'` would have done it, but it must work differently with a heatmap. You may need to adjust your `tickPositions` by adding (or subtracting) a fraction. Try `-0.5, 1.5, 3.5`, etc, and see what works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tickmarkPlacement: 'between'` to achieve the desired tick positions. To position the label you can use `labels.y` property:

```
    labels: {
        y: -25
    }
```

---

**Live working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/2q50sdbc/

**API references:**

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.y
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickmarkPlacement

Comment: labels are placed but tick remains in the same place that is middle

Comment: Please provide some live working example of this issue.